# Multiplying arrays with broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an mxn A matrix and an nxr B matrix that I want to multiply in a specific way to get an mxr matrix. I want to multiply every element in the ith column of A as a scalar to the ith row of B and the sum the n matrices

For example

```
a = [[0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 5],

b = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

The product would be

```
a*b = [[0, 0, 0, 0],  +  [[4, 5, 6, 7],      +  [[16, 18, 20, 22],  =  [[20, 23, 26, 29],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]]      [16, 20, 24, 28]]      [40, 45, 50, 55]]      [56, 68, 80, 92]]
```

I can't use any loops so I'm pretty sure I have to use broadcasting but I don't know how. Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input matrices are of shape (2, 3) and (3, 4) respectively and the result you want is of shape (2, 4).

What you need is just a [dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) product of your two matrices as

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 5]])

b = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 10, 11]])

print (np.dot(a,b))

# array([[20, 23, 26, 29],
#        [56, 68, 80, 92]])
```

Comment: Haha wow I've been awake for too long. Totally forgot that's how matrix multiplication works